# How to post to a view in django from a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Heres the scenario:

I have a email subscriber/un-subscriber app. I am stuck up in the un-subscribing a user part. The user is given a link, which if he/she follows will be able to un-subscribe. The link is typically a view, in the following format:

```
r^'/unsub_view/(?P<user_id>\w+)/$'
```

So, when the user follows this links he/she is doing a `GET` request on the view `unsub_view` with a parameter user_id. So I have coded up my view as:

```
def unsub_view(request, user_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ### Do some DB lookup to determine if it is a valid user or not
            if user_is_valid:
                return direct_to_template(request, '/app/unsub.html', {'user': user})
```

Now when a valid user is doing the `GET`, a confirmation dialogue is shown, along with a button. If he/she clicks on the button, I want the template to post the `'user'` to the same view, thus the `unsub_view` also has this piece of code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if user_is_subscribed:
        #Unsubscribe the user.
    else:
        #Show error meessage.
```

**My question is** how can I have the button in my template to post to this view ? I have looked around but I got POST-ing to a .php or .asp 
Please help.

Note: If there is a better workflow idea, I am also open to that, so please do suggest if there is one.

Comment: Forms can make post requests, you can use a form with something simple like a hidden input, a submit button and a button that will take you back to the previous page.

Comment: Not sure why you think posting to a Django view would be any different from posting to a PHP or ASP page.

Comment: @DanielRoseman umm, not different. Its that there is a PHP file right? I cannot co-relate this with a view. Can you explain please? I am confused.

Comment: You don't post to a file, you post to a URL. We have URLs in Django too.

Comment: ah! so if I do something like: `<form name="myform" method="post" action="/unsub_view/">`
 It is expected to work?

Comment: It works. Thanks a ton! But since my view takes `user_id` as parameter, I am posting to `/unsub_view/{{ use_id }}`

Comment: have a read at this to understand a little bit better https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template unsub.html rendering the form with the button, you should pass the url of your view using the reverse method

```
     from django.code.urlresolvers import reverse


     def unsub_view(request, viewid):
         if request.method == 'POST':
            if user_is_subscribed:
                #Unsubscribe the user.
                submit_url = reverse('unsub_view', viewid)
                return direct_to_template(request, '/app/unsub.html', {'user': user, 'submit_url'})
            else:
                #Show error meessage.
```

in your template you can then render the form like follows :

```
...
<form method='post' action='{{ submit_url }}'>
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="hidden" value="{{ user_id }}" name="user_id" />
     <input type="submit" value="unsubscribe"/>
</form>
...
```

Django also has a full framework dedicated to form modeling and rendering. You could take advantage of that to generate the form.

Comment: Don't forget to add the csrf token to forms that are going to be 'POST'ed.